# Avoiding empty page between a very full page and the index?

Tags: indexing, tufte, blank-page

I'm getting an empty page between the last page of the book and the index. The reason seems to be an over-full last page of text. I'm already using **openany**.

In the following example, all the "bla" lines are on the first page, the second page is blank (erroneously), and the third page contains the index. Commenting one line of "bla" fixes the situation: the first page contains the lines of "bla" and the second page contains the index. Is there anything else I can do? (Is this a bug I should report?)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,twoside,notitlepage]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\title{Test}
\author{Alex Schroeder}
\begin{document}

\maketitle% this prints the handout title, author, and date

\newthought{Test}\index{Test}.

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

bla

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: When I tried your document here with `pdflatex` and `makeindex`, it placed one `bla` on page two and the index started on page 3. Can you add `\listfiles` to the preamble of your document and then paste the dates/versions of all the packages you're using (from the bottom of your `.log` file)?

Comment: The problem seems due to the `\begin{fullwidth}` with which `\theindex` starts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's odd.

```
\enlargethispage{5pt}
\printindex
```

Is a work around, but it shouldn't happen really....